# Virtual Machines all got restarted together, how to avoid that?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network, azure-affinity-group

My virtual machines got restarted together by fabric controller. I think this is because I set them all in one virtual network and one affinity group. How can I avoid them been restarted together? They must be in the same network

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting up redundant virtual machines and using [availability sets](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/articles/manage-availability-virtual-machines/) ensures that your service will remain online during maintenance operations by the fabric controller (like the one that occured this weekend).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, should I place them all in one availability set? or different?

Comment: As the documentation states: *An update domain is used to ensure that not all of the virtual machine instances are updated at the same time. When you assign multiple virtual machines to an availability set, Windows Azure ensures that the machines are assigned to different update domains.* That means all redundant VMs serving the same purpose should get an availability set.